# [Error] Timeout: Aborted finding home position for channel 7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error message shows during homing process. After that, Finger pinky stopped moving, the motor drived for it got very hot, so I turned off power for security. Anyone who meets simlar problem? How to fix it? And what's the reason?

Here's the message:

```
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 5 mA
DiverSVH(Error) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Timeout: Aborted finding home position for channel 7
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Driving channel 7 to hardstop. Detection thresholds: Current MIN: -225.000000mA MAX: -225.000000mA
DiverSVH(Info) SVHFingerManager::resetChannel: Resetting channel 7: Pinky current: 237 mA
```

Message stopped here.

Finger Pinky actually moved twice before the error message shows. So the motor drived for it seems has not broken.
I also tried to turn the power off and on, shut roscore down, reset several times. However, the same problem still happened everytime.

Anyone who meets simlar problem?
How to fix it?
And what's the reason?

Any help is apperatiated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221493/%5Berror%5D-timeout:-aborted-finding-home-position-for-channel-7/) by [SubaruX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25171/subarux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello SubaruX,

this looks like a cable problem. During reset the current controller is supposed to ramp up its current until it reaches its threshold (225mA in this case) which indicates a hard stop and is used for referencing the finger.

In the top of your output the current is not climbing at all but rather staying at an arbitrary low value. When the timeout occurs, the whole process is stopped , everything is reconfigured and then started aggain. This time the Pinky drove immediately to 237mA which should be enough to trigger the reset, however, i suspect that no encoder ticks are read, leading to a stall. I will look into the driver and see if I can detect this special case in the future.

You will most likely have to get the cabling of your SVH checked. Until then, consider deactivating the Pinky in the config file to continue work without damaging the hand.

Best Regards
Georg

---

Originally posted by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) with karma: 55 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0